# how can I get F# language reference from VS 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, f#

I have installed the May 2009 CTP. And I would like to read F# language reference offline, instead of having to visit msdn.microsoft.com. How can I do that?

(Also, I noticed in early releases of F# you could right click a keyword and then select from menu 'Go to Definition' and VS would show some source code. I cannot do that anymore, why?)

**UPDATE** THe following is a reply I got in a F# forum from the Technical Writer for F#

View the complete topic at: http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/thread/11238.aspx

*Posted By: gordonh in General Discussions on F# 
Subject: Re: VS 2008 and F# and MSDN Library: how can I locally install F# language reference?

---

That's expected, since those docs only reflect what's in the packaged release of VS 2008 which did not include F#.
For now you have only the online option in the Dev10 Beta1 docs (and the F# Library docs on the MSR site), but there is no local option for docs.  This will change as we get Dev10 finished up and released.  Dev10 will have local and online F# docs for the language and the core library.
Gordon Hogenson, Technical Writer for F#*

Comment: I mean the MSDN F# Language Reference. I can access VB.NET and C#. Online MSDN Library only show documentation in the section under  MSDN Library\Dev Tools and Lang\VS 2010 Beta 1\Visual Studio\Visual F#\F# Language Reference.

Well, maybe it is available after downloading VS 2010 Pro Beta 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can access the documentation offline. Documentation for the [F# language on the MSDN website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233181(VS.100).aspx) and even that is preliminary and will possibly change. I know you are referring specifically to VS2008, but you may wish to note that all documentation/help will be hosted online with VS2010.  In other words, there will be no offline option for any of the .NET languages.

Comment: Your answer is the closest, but the final answer is in the UPDATE which is some info I got from the source itself. Anyway I am marking your answer as the accepted and make this post appear as ANSWERED.

Comment: Great. I guess the closest counts in SO and HorseShoes. Thanks for following up with you own update. Good stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about how to view the reference offline, but the go to definition issue is a bug with the latest release. [see here](http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/thread/10654.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just visit once and download it to your local machine?  It's available it single page form at the following location and can just be saved locally

- http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html

I believe there are PDF versions available as well but I can't seem to find them right now.

Comment: I don't think he means the spec, i think he wants the MSDN Reference offline.